# Alertbox in javascript without Exclamation

Tags: javascript, alert

Can any one please let me knwo how can we display a message box / alert box in Javascript without the **Exclamation** symbol in the message box.

Using VB script we can use the below items.

0 : Blank icon 
16: White cross in red circle
32: Question bubble
48: Exclamation Mark in yellow triangle 
64: Exclamation in bubble

Is there anything like this for javascript..?

Comment: No, except use a browser, which doesn't show symbols at all.

Comment: In a browser? In a command prompt?

Comment: Why post and vanish? x-|

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using jQuery UI as mentioned below:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
```

Please have a look at below URL:

- [JQuery UI Alert](https://plugins.jquery.com/ui.dialog/)
- [JQueru UI Demo](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Answer (score 0):

No, that is browser dependent. For example chrome shows the chrome icon instead of exclamation.

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert

If you want to customise it, you have to implement an overlay with jquery or your own JS by adding a DIV